# Keeping Bootstrap columns within viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a Bootstrap project that uses columns, cards and `justify-content-between` to spread things out evenly.

The problem I am seeing is that on `medium` size breakpoints (e.g. iPads), the right-most card overflows off-screen.

I want to avoid the need for the user to scroll horizontally and so want to keep all content within the visible viewport.

Sample code : https://codepen.io/6a0a49af-a3f9-4e78-8ccf-91d8d1b1f102/pen/QWKYJqM

Screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/9sqT4DF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you. You need to apply `max-width: 100%;` to the `.gscustomwidth`. This issue arrives because the width given by you is more than its parent element.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/ahdrpckw/2/

Comment: Super. Thank you. I guess it's easy if you know how !  ;-)

Comment: First of all, We are glad that, our solution helped you...
"gscustomwidth" block width (45vw or 25vw) is larger than its parent div "col" so we have set max-width (100%).
Now  "gscustomwidth" block width will not be greater than its parent div "col".